# Convert a NO push button into an On/Off button

Tags: switches, relay, 12v, button

I'm building a boombox, and it needs a couple of switches for main on/off, voltmeter on/off and LED lights on/off. Since I don't have any metalworking tools I am going to buy a premade front panel, [this one](http://store.accusafe.nl/accecoires/panelen/inbouw-schotel-zwart-130x90mm-bewerkt). It has room for an on/off switch, and two NO push buttons  These push buttons are momentary, so they will only let electricity flow while the button is pressed. This is ok for the voltmeter, but it gets a bit tiring to hold down the button when you want the LED lights to turn on!

I've looked at some JK relays such as this [74107 relay](http://elektronik-lavpris.dk/p131773/74107N_Dual_J-K_flip-flop_with_clear_DIP-14/). However, looking at the datasheet, it only supports voltages ranging from 4.75V to 5.25V, and the boombox is 12V. And even if it worked for higher voltages, I'm confused about what pins to connect where.

Can someone please point me in the direction of a relay that supports higher voltages, or perhaps another, easier solution? Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear whether you already had the NO pushbuttons, and had to use those, or could use another type of pushbutton.  If so, you might look at "alternate action" buttons, push-on, push off [like this one](http://www.mpja.com/SPDT-Push-Button-Switch-Alternate-Action-12VDC-Green/productinfo/31376%20SW/) rated at 12v.  If too big, you can just search for others like it.

Comment: I don't have the buttons yet, and would gladly invest in something else that works better. The panel has no datasheet that I can find, so I don't know whether buttons I buy would fit. I'll try emailing the manufacturers, perhaps they have one that just isn't publicly available.

Comment: Just get regular latching push on push off buttons? The panel has holes,  doesn't matter what you put there as long as it fits.